# server side validation for jsp with jquery

Tags: jquery, jsp

I want to do server side validation with jquery. but I do not know how to start with this stuff. are there any good tutorials with examples to learn server-side validation with jquery for jsp?

Comment: jQuery is run on the client's side... You want your validation to happen on the server side... This has nothing to do with jQuery... Once the data has been sent to the server, only the server is in charge of the validation...

Comment: As @p0rter said, this is really a question for Google.

Answer (score 1):

If u want to do this anyhow,

Then You need to use Ajax framework like DWR(Direct Web REmoting) with jQuery.
By using this Ajax framework U could call ur validator functions (Server side functions written in Java). And then in jQuery callback functions, U could render error messages or whatever logic you want to implement.

These links may help you.

http://numberformat.wordpress.com/2010/09/21/direct-web-remoting-dwr-hello-world-example/

[sample program with DWR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6623795/sample-program-with-dwr)

http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/introduction/scripting-dwr.html

Answer (score 0):

JQuery is browser side Javascript library.

You can only use JQuery to do Client Side validations.

For Server Side validations you need a server side language.

In your case you need to do the validation in Java. 
Tell us more about the framework you currently have.